# Select instance having an attribute included in an array

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm using Public Activity to create a feed, and I'd like to filter the activities. I don't want to show to the `current_user` its own activities so I have:

```
@activities = PublicActivity::Activity.where.not(owner_id: current_user.id)
```

And this works well. I want to add a second filter, which is to only display activities that belong to the users followed by `current_user`.

I can get all the followed users using:

```
@users = current_user.following
```

My question is: how can I filter the activities by checking if `owner_id` is the id of a user included in `@users` ?

EDIT:

`activities` table:

```
create_table "activities", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "trackable_id"
    t.string   "trackable_type"
    t.integer  "owner_id"
    t.string   "owner_type"
    t.string   "key"
    t.text     "parameters"
    t.integer  "recipient_id"
    t.string   "recipient_type"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.boolean  "read",           default: false
    t.string   "origin"
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
Activity.joins(:owner).where.not(
           users: {id: current_user.id}
       ).joins(owner: :followings).where(
           followings: { follower_id: current_user.id }
       )
```

This translates to all activities DO NOT belonging to the `current_user` but DO belong to a user followed by `current_user`.

You may need to replace values were appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Howerver, I get this error: 
Association named 'users' was not found on PublicActivity::Activity

This might be due to the fact that by default, the activities table as a owner_id attribute but not a user. Should I add a reference to the user table in the activity table ? I've edited my question with the table

Comment: No need to change the reference when a simple change to query  will do: `Activity.joins(:owners)`. See my update

Comment: Same error: Association named 'owners' was not found on PublicActivity::Activity

Comment: Then do `:owner` instead of owners

Comment: Whatever the relation is named goes in the `joins`

Comment: Ok it "worked" since it changed the error: 
Cannot eagerly load the polymorphic association :owner